# UIAlert View Objective C - Opening app store link

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, app-store, uialertview

```
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"An Alert!" 
                                                   delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://phobos.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=301349397&amp;amp;amp;amp;mt=8"]];];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
```

I'm trying to display a UIAlertView with one "Ok" button and one "Buy Full Version" button. How can i make the above code work?

Thanks

Comment: The methods takes button titles, not arbitrary code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to handle the button click in the [`UIAlertViewDelegate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertViewDelegate_Protocol/UIAlertViewDelegate/UIAlertViewDelegate.html) that you specify.

Also, `otherButtonTitles` is simply a `va_list` of `NSString` objects to use as titles, you set what happens when they are tapped in `UIAlertViewDelegate`'s `alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:` method:

```
- (void) alertView:(UIAlertView *) alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger) index {
    if(index == 1) {
       [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://phobos.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=301349397&amp;amp;amp;amp;mt=8"]];
    }
}
```

Don't forget to set the `delegate`:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"An Alert!" 
                                                            delegate:self
                                                   cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                   otherButtonTitles:@"Buy Full Version"];
[alert show];
[alert release];
```

Comment: Just to make it more clear **benhowdle89** in case  you didn't understand, the most important step here is that you conform to the `UIAlertViewDelegate` protocol.  You can do that in your interface using `<UIAlertViewDelegate>`.